# Auto init of a static class that extends parent

Tags: php, oop

I have a class called `Foo` with a constructor and I want to have one variable of it to be the name of the child class.

Example:

```
class Foo {

    protected static $name;
    protected static $something;

    public function __construct( $something ) {
        self::$something = $something;
        self::$name = strtolower( __CLASS__ );
    }

    static public function hello() {
        echo self::$name;
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo {}

new Foo( 'lazy' );
Bar::hello();
```

The result will be always `foo()`, because the constructor is called only by `new Foo()`.

So, what is the way? Is there a magic method called when a static method is invoked? Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: https://eval.in/569930

Comment: Thanks, but this not solve. I need to store it in a variable without recall each time the function. Hello need to be just a viewer of the variable, not an hyphotetic setter.

Comment: *I need to store it in a variable* - when it will be if you dom't want to call construct ?

Comment: That was the question. The question ( at the end ) was: is there a magic method invoked each time a method is called? ( So with this I can check if the variable is declared or not )

Comment: Yes, the result will always be `foo` what did you expect it to be? Always `bar`? Sometimes `bar`? Which times `bar` and which times `foo`?

Answer (score 0):

`get_called_class()` should be used instead of `__CLASS__` magic constant.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

More info in the manual : [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: Always in the construct? I don't want to execute another function for each class to set the $name variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @JesusTheHun said, first of all you'll want to change `__CLASS__` to either `get_called_class()` or `static::class` (as of PHP 5.5). The string `__CLASS__` gets read at compile-time, and will always refer to the class in which it's specified. Either of the other options will take effect at run-time.

However, by setting a static class variable in a constructor, you're changing that variable for **all instances** of the class (past and present) as well as changing it for any static calls. So whenever a instance of any class in the tree is instantiated, all future calls to hello() will display that class name, i.e.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    protected static $name;
    protected static $something;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$name = strtolower( static::class );
    }

    static public function hello() {
        echo self::$name;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {}
class Baz extends Foo {}

new Foo;
Bar::hello(); // "foo"
new Baz;
Bar::hello(); // "baz"
```

This seems like it probably isn't the behaviour you're looking for. If all you want is a static method that will echo the class name that called it, then you can use one of the methods above, e.g.

```
    static public function hello() {
        echo static::class;
    }
```

Comment: Mh, yes, I thought this soultion, but I need to not init each time the class ( so avoid new Baz ). I think there's no automatic way.

Comment: @Grork I'm not sure I understand then. If you want a static method that will echo the appropriate class name, then use the hello() method at the end of my answer. If you want it to return something else, then it sounds like what you're looking for isn't a static method at all.

Comment: Well. You're right. I think I wll use this. Thanks!